# How can I seperate drop targets using React DnD

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-dnd

I'm using React Dnd v16.0.1. All containers and images being rendered are coming from JSON data and using map to render out elements. The problem I'm having is I have two droppable containers (which only one allows me to drop), when I drop an image on the droppable container that allows me both containers take up the same image dropped.

[image]

I just dragged an image to the right container which is the only one that allows me for some weird reason because im using map to render these containers from JSON data and as you can see both containers took up the image even though I dragged it to the right container.

Below is the code that renders the draggable images on the bottom and the black border drop targets containers. As you see below I'm using const [board, setBoard] = useState([]); which then I use to render the new images dragged, but how could i seperate this state per container?

```
const [board, setBoard] = useState([]);
  let dragDropCounter = 0;
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  const [{ isOver }, drop] = useDrop({
    accept: "image",
    drop: (item) => addImageToBoard(item.id),
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isOver: !!monitor.isOver()
    })
  });

  const addImageToBoard = (id) => {
    // console.log(id);
    const pictureList = draggableItems.filter((item) => id === item.props.id);
    console.log(pictureList);

    setBoard((board) => [...board, pictureList[0].props]);
  };

  if (fields[0]) {
    for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
      fields[i]?.drag?.map((dragData, x) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-key
        draggableItems.push(
          // <div>
          <Img
            fieldsPosX={dragData?.pos?.x}
            fieldsPosY={dragData?.pos?.y}
            fieldsWidth={dragData?.pos?.wid}
            fieldsHeight={dragData?.pos?.ht}
            type={dragData?.type}
            id={x}
            useReff={ref}
            currentValue={number}
            currentId={currentInputId}
            url={dragData?.img}
          />
          // </div>
        );
        dragDropCounter = x;
        dragDropCounter++;
      });

      fields[i]?.drop?.map((dropData, index) => {
        dropTargets.push(
          <div
            className="Board"
            ref={drop}
            key={dragDropCounter}
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              border: "2px solid black",
              top: `${dropData?.pos?.x}px`,
              left: `${dropData?.pos?.y}px`,
              height: `${dropData?.pos?.ht}px`,
              width: `${dropData?.pos?.wid}px`
            }}>
            {board.map((picture, index) => {
              return (
                <Img
                  key={index}
                  url={picture.url}
                  id={picture.id}
                  type={picture.type}
                  draggedElement={"true"}
                />
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
        dragDropCounter++;
      });
      // console.log(dropTargets);
    }
    return [draggableItems, dropTargets];
  }
```

Draggable Image component:

```
const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag(() => ({
    type: "image",
    item: { id: id },
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging()
    })
  }));

  return (
    <>
      {type === "IMG" ? (
        <img
          src={url}
          ref={drag}
          onClick={(e) => handleChange(e)}
          id={`input-text${id}`}
          name={"test"}
          value={currentId == `input-text${id}` ? currentValue : null}
          style={{
            border: isDragging ? "5px solid pink" : "0px",
            position: draggedElement ? "relative" : "absolute",
            top: `${fieldsPosX}px`,
            left: `${fieldsPosY}px`,
            background: isDragging ? "pink" : "blue",
            height: `50px`,
            maxWidth: `50px`,
            width: "100%",
            zIndex: "40",
            touchAction: "none"
          }}
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to have separate drop targets, so in my original code I had my drag component seperate from my drop component but once i combined the two components into one and used drag(drop(ref)) insead of drop(ref) and drag(reg) in those seperate files, my drop targets were now seperate and I was able to drop any image to any target without duplicating on both drop targets.